# Is the closure of an interior set in a general metric space significant in any way?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Assume the interior set is an interior set of a subset of a larger metric space

As the title says, in a generic metric space, would the closure of a set of interior points just be the boundary? I am having trouble picturing this and can't find any related questions online

Comment: What is an "interior set"?

Comment: The set of interior points of a set

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me what your question is. Is it the following?
"If $X$ is a metric space and $A$ is a subset of $X$ is the closure of the interior of $A$ the boundary of $A$?".

The answer to that is no. Some counterexamples:

If $X=\Bbb R^2$ and $A=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2<1\}$, then the closure of the
interior of $A$ is $\{(x,y):x^2+y^2\le 1\}$ but the boundary of $A$ is $\{(x,y):x^2+y^2=1\}$.

If $X=\Bbb R^2$ and $A=\{(x,0):x\in\Bbb R\}$, then the closure of the
interior of $A$ is empty, but the boundary of $A$ is $A$.

Comment: Yes that is what I meant, apologies. Does the Interior set of A itself have a boundary made up of its own limit points?

Answer (score 1):

The closure-of-the-interior operation **often arises** when [topological operators](https://www.google.com/search?q="topological+operators"+exterior+interior+complement+closure) play an important role, such as the [Kuratowski's closure-complement problem](https://www.google.com/search?q=topology+Kuratowski+interior+closure), and it **does arise** in the notion of a [regular closed set](https://www.google.com/search?q="regular+closed+set") (also called a [regularly closed set](https://www.google.com/search?q="regularly+closed+set")).